# Get folder directory via file explorer

Tags: c++, windows, directory

I am working on a basic 3D visualiser project but have run into a speed bump.

The application gives you the option to create a new project. What I need is it to open windows file explorer to let the user select a directory to set up the project.

Currently I use this

```
const int BUFSIZE = 1024;
char buffer[BUFSIZE] = { 0 };
OPENFILENAME ofns = { 0 };
ofns.lStructSize = sizeof(ofns);
ofns.lpstrFile = buffer;
ofns.nMaxFile = BUFSIZE;
ofns.lpstrTitle = "Select Directory";
GetOpenFileName(&ofns);
std::string directory = buffer;
```

But this forces you to select a file meaning it can't be an empty folder (which it needs to be).

What do I need to use to grab the directory of an empty folder through file explorer using c++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IFileSaveDialog to present an interface that is directories only.

Create a CLSID_FileSaveDialog getting the IFileSaveDialog interface then use the SetOptions call to specify at least FOS_PICKFOLDERS

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I spent some time going through the docs for this and it has confused me!

I get that I need to do this:


    IFileSaveDialog* pFileOpen;
 
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileSaveDialog, NULL, 
    CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IFileSaveDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>
   (&pFileOpen));

Then then use pFileOpen->SetOptions(FOS_PICKFOLDERS);

But as for getting the window to open I have no idea! :(